# having issues while connecting tomcat to mysql in a docker container?

Tags: mysql, docker, tomcat8, docker-swarm

I have 2 docker services created via docker-swarm.

One is Tomcat and the other is mysql, i am trying to connect from tomcat to mysql both are in different containers.

here is my `hibernate.cfg.xml` in tomcat container.

```
<property name="connection.url">
            jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/travelbiz
        </property>
        <property name="connection.username">trvlbz_admin</property>
        <property name="connection.password">admin123</property>
```

and here is the service running

```
root@ubuntu:/home/smadmin# docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                                                                                                 COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
2ecb386d9bbc        cloudesire/tomcat@sha256:19e24a2290e4c3253a44d65243a54c520e9f8e0fe0edf3a5221ccc67cf9da0f8             "/run.sh"                7 hours ago         Up 7 hours          8080/tcp            apache.2.1ftla1ohbnjgax7ibk8fbh5hz
4e940f3be18d        vishnuranganathan/vishmysql@sha256:4460004d01c9a23d4c80ea2a9d7a69fc1495cbe01b48555cf28bd73a535176d1   "/usr/bin/mysqld_safe"   7 hours ago         Up 7 hours          3306/tcp            mysql.1.hjoba4bsrl8lujfumc6qru3uq
```

i am getting mysql connection refused exception when trying to access via tomcat.can someone help me on this ?

Comment: Did you check if the mysql configuration in the container is allowing external connections? It would be in the my.cnf file, the configuration is the `bind_address 0.0.0.0` or just remove it.

Comment: @JorgeCampos  yeah i change to 0.0.0.0  still same issue, 
in hibernate.cfg.xml in tomcat container :
<property name="connection.url">
            jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/travelbiz
        </property>

it should be localhost (or) host-ip (or) mysql-container-id  ??

Comment: `localhost` that's your problem then. It should be the IP address of the mysql container, not localhost.

Comment: @JorgeCampos Mysql Container ip works Thanks

Comment: Glad to help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not want to use the ip address of the mysql container as that is bound to change the next time a new mysql container is started or if you happen to scale it (may not be easy with mysql though). What you should ideally use is the name of the container. When you brought up the container you would have used `docker run`, make sure to add `--name mysql` and then use `mysql` instead of the ip address.

Comment: yeah i agree with you point Anoop. i am using Swarm to bring the containers up and not the docker run command.

can i use service name instead of container name when i use Docker-swarm ??

Comment: Yes, absolutely. Using the service name is very useful as you may be scaling up the service to have multiple replicas. You want a single service name to reach however many replicas you may have.